# is my script right about 0 or 1 marker in bounds - google map JS API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bounds

When bounds have 0 or 1 marker.position, the resultat on map is often something not what I want.
To resolve this problem, I write this code and MyFunction, but it is clean or durty ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map; 
var bounds;
var markers = [];
var data = {....,....}; 
var mapcen = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8667,2.3333);
...
function initialize()
{    map = new google.maps.Map ( document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
     {    zoom: 5,
          center: mapcen,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     } );
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) 
    {   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ ... });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
}
...
function MyFunction ()
{    var nb = 0;
     bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     for(var i=0 ; i < ... ; i++)
     {    if(markers[i] ...)
          {    markers[i].setMap(map);
               bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
               nb++;
          }
          else
          {    markers[i].setMap(null);
          }
     }
     if(nb==0)
     {    bounds.extend(mapcen);
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);
     var listener = google.maps.event.addListener ( map, "idle", function() 
     {    if (map.getZoom() > 13) map.setZoom(13); 
          if (map.getZoom() < 5) map.setZoom(5); 
          google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
     } );
}
...
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

Thank you for yours suggestions.

I hope this code can help somebody, because I need realy 2 days to find this solution.

Sorry for my poor english

PS : I cannot add bounds.extend in tags of this post

Comment: I am not sure, but with google map
when bounds have 0 position, the position is 0,0 and zoom 7
when bound have 1 position, zoom is 21.

Is it possible to define 
- zoom and position when bounds have 0 position
- zoom when bouns have 1 position

In MyFunction I try with map.zoom, but after zoom is fix, also when bounds have several position.
     `code`
    ` if(nb==0)
     {    bounds.extend(mapcen);   
          map.setZoom(5);
     }
     if(nb==1)
     {    map.setZoom(13);
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);`
`code`

Comment: How can I format code when I add a Comment ?